# Create all possible combinations on a list string with wildcards

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list of strings, where the strings can have the format of:
`property1`, `property1_property2`, `property1_property2_property3`.
This list of strings are then used for comparison against a concatenated string on a given set of properties:

```
public List<string> EnabledSettings = new List<string> { "pizza_milk_iceCream", "meatballs_water_slushy", "sallad_tea_candy" };
```

Then we have a class for each variant of this list of string:

```
public enum Food
{
    Pizza,
    Meatballs,
    Sallad,
    Soup
}
public enum Drink
{
    Milk,
    Beer,
    Water,
    Tea
}
public enum Dessert
{
    IceCream,
    Slushy,
    Cookies,
    Candy
}

public class FeatureOne
{
    public List<string> EnabledSettings = new List<string> { "pizza_milk_iceCream", "meatballs_water_slushy", "sallad_tea_candy" };
    public bool IsEnabled(Food food, Drink drink, Dessert dessert) => EnabledSettings.Contains($"{food}_{drink}_{dessert}");
}

public class FeatureTwo
{
    public List<string> EnabledSettings = new List<string> { "pizza_milk", "meatballs_water", "sallad_tea" };
    public bool IsEnabled(Food food, Drink drink) => EnabledSettings.Contains($"{food}_{drink}");
}
```

Now I would like to introduce a wildcard to be able to mark some properties as optional e.g. `property1_*_property3` or `property1_property2_*` etc.

How would I go about handling that, in a more generic way?

What I started with was something like below. To have each feature class define what fields are applicable for each feature and which (if any) should be optional or not. Then create a collection of all possible permutations based on that, to eventually compare against the settings provided

```
public record SettingField(string Value, bool Optional);
public enum Food
{
    Pizza,
    Meatballs,
    Sallad,
    Soup
}
public enum Drink
{
    Milk,
    Beer,
    Water,
    Tea
}
public enum Dessert
{
    IceCream,
    Slushy,
    Cookies,
    Candy
}
public class FeatureOne
{
    public List<string> EnabledSettings = new List<string> { "pizza_milk_iceCream", "pizza_beer_*", "meatballs_water_slushy", "meatballs_*_cookies", "sallad_tea_candy" };
    public bool IsEnabled(Food food, Drink drink, Dessert dessert)
    {
        var fields = new List<SettingField>
        {
            new SettingField(food.ToString(), false),
            new SettingField(drink.ToString(), true),
            new SettingField(dessert.ToString(), true)
        };
        var variants = new List<string>(); // All possible permutations based on above given fields
        return variants.Any(x => EnabledSettings.Contains(x));
    }
}

public class FeatureTwo
{
    public List<string> EnabledSettings = new List<string> { "pizza_milk", "meatballs_water", "sallad_tea", "soup_*" };
    public bool IsEnabled(Food food, Drink drink)
    {
        var fields = new List<SettingField>
        {
            new SettingField(food.ToString(), false),
            new SettingField(drink.ToString(), true)
        };
        var variants = new List<string>(); // All possible permutations based on above given fields
        return variants.Any(x => EnabledSettings.Contains(x));
    }
}

// Usage
bool featureOneEnabled = new FeatureOne().IsEnabled("pizza_beer_pancakes");
Console.WriteLine(featureOneEnabled) => false // would love to see this true
```

I'm not sure how to get all possible permutations, taking the optional parameter into considerations. Nor do I know if this would even be the preferred way of tackling this. I'll happily take any advice on the matter

## Edit

I forot one crucial part, that is that the properties are of type enum.
Worth mentioning is also that the EnabledSettings list are provided outside of the application.

Comment: Your description and your code seem to contradict each other a little. It seems your `List<string> EnabledSettings` already incorporates a fixed position of the settings and it has the optional `*` in some. Yet in your `SettingField` class you declare some of the items optional as well. It's unclear if both can be optional or not and then why you think you need "all possible combinations".

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry for the lack of clarity. I made an edit since I forgot to set the parameter as enum. The EnabledSettings are defined elsewhere, outside of the application code. I considered the `SettingField` setup in the respective feature classes as some kind of ruleset for how I can expect part of the string to look. So in FeatureTwo I mark drink as optional. Then I can expect the following combinations: "Pizza_*", "Meatballs_*", "Sallad_*", "Soup_*" but also "Pizza_Milk", "Meatballs_Milk", "Sallad_Milk", "Soup_Milk", "Sallad_Beer" etc. etc. But I obviously don't want to type those out

Comment: Maybe another way of going could be to only let the incoming EnabledSettings decide what are optional and not. So in case I would get a string like `"Pizza_*"` I would know that Pizza is forced but it could be any drink. Then I could actually split the string on `_` and if it would be a `*` at a given position I would allow all enum values on that position

Comment: It still seems a bit unclear. Why are incoming values optional and the patterns also contains `*`. Does that make it doubly optional? What's the need behind this code? I suspect you're not really trying to model food choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string functions `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` to accomplish this goal without changing your data.  Essentially create a string for the start check (food, food+drink) and a string for the end check (drink, drink+dessert, dessert).  Then check each string in the settings to see if they match both the start and end comparison strings.

```
public bool IsEnabled(string food, string drink, string dessert)
{
    // Check which arguments are wildcards
    //
    var wildFood = food == "*";
    var wildDrink = drink == "*";
    var wildDessert = dessert == "*";

    // Indicators, all wild cards and when to use StartsWith & EndsWith
    //
    var allWild = wildFood && wildDrink && wildDessert;
    var requiresStartOrEndCheck = !allWild && (wildFood || wildDrink || wildDessert);

    // Initialized empty for StartsWith and EndsWith to work without additional conditions
    //
    var startCheckString = "";
    var endCheckString = "";

    if (requiresStartOrEndCheck)
    {
        // Construct the StartsWith string
        //
        if (!wildFood)
        {
            startCheckString = food;

            if (!wildDrink)
            {
                startCheckString += "_" + drink;
            }
        }

        // Construct the EndsWith string
        //
        else
        {
            if (!wildDrink)
            {
                endCheckString = "_" + drink;

                if (!wildDessert)
                {
                    endCheckString += "_" + dessert;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                endCheckString = dessert;
            }
        }

        // Check if any settings match using StartsWith and EndsWith strings
        //
        return EnabledSettings.Any(setting => 
            setting.StartsWith(startCheckString) && 
            setting.EndsWith(endCheckString)
        );
    }

    // True when all params are wildcards, 
    // or when the string literal is in the list; otherwise false
    //
    return allWild || EnabledSettings.Contains($"{food}_{drink}_{dessert}");
}
```